# Formula for the roots of a cubic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, cubics

I know that you can derive a quadratic formula from the given complex roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ if you simply put them into the formula $x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta=0$. Is there an equivalent for cubic equations?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano's_method

Comment: @Community : "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : no it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking is this: if you know the roots of a cubic polynomial, then can you get the expression for the polynomial itself? And the answer is you can: if a cubic has roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, then the formula for the cubic is just $$(x - \alpha) (x - \beta) (x - \gamma)$$ which expands to $$ x^3 - (\alpha + \beta + \gamma)x^2 + (\alpha \beta + \beta \gamma + \gamma \alpha) x - \alpha \beta \gamma.$$

The quadratic formula that you posted likewise, is just the expansion of $(x - \alpha)(x - \beta)$.

Comment: Thank you, and it can still be the case that one of the roots is real whilst the other two are the complex conjugate pair in that trio of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, correct?

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference if the roots are real or complex. In fact, all three roots can be complex (though in this case, some of the coefficients of the expanded polynomial will also be complex).

Comment: @ElDorado In effect, Connor Harris' answer indicates that [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) applies to 3rd degree equations, as well as 2nd degree equations.  In fact, this formula applies to a polynomial of any degree $n ~: n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, and the question of whether any of the roots are Complex rather than Real is (as indicated by Connor Harris) always irrelevant.

Comment: In the case of an equation such as $2x^3 + px^2 + 20x + q=0$, where the roots are $3+2i, 3-2i, and -2$, do I just replace the value of $p$ and $q$ for $(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)$ and $\alpha \beta \gamma $ in order to find those two variables?

Comment: @ElDorado Re your *cut off* comment, then $p = (-1) \times [(3 + 2i) + (3-2i) + (-2)]$ and $q = (-1) \times [(3 + 2i) \times (3-2i) \times (-2)]$.

Comment: @ElDorado Also, re your comment, the coefficient of $(20)$ is wrong.  According to Vieta's formula, if the roots of the cubic are $r_1, r_2, r_3$ (which may not necessarily be 3 distinct numbers), then the coefficient of the $(x)$ term will be $(+1) \times [(r_1 r_2) + (r_1 r_3) + (r_2 r_3)].$